# copy a directory into multiple directories

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

I have structure like A directory `dir_a/dir_b` and `dir_c/dir_d` to `dir_z` or some other 100 names.

now I need to copy `dir_b` into `dir_d` and all other sub-directories in `dir_c`. And a part from that every-time I need to copy `dir_b` into `dir_c` sub directories it should prompt me confirmation with `you want to copy dir_b into dir_d [Y/N]`

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the target directories. Use `read` to ask the user, I added another loop to only get `y` or `n`.

```
#! /bin/bash
for target in dir_c/dir_{d..z} ; do

    answer=''
    until [[ $answer == [YyNn] ]] ; do
        read -p "Copy dir_a/dir_b into $target? (y/n) " answer
    done

    if [[ $answer == [Yy] ]] ; then
        cp -r dir_a/dir_b "$target"
    fi
done
```

Comment: No , my friend that structure I gave for example. So to clarify I mentioned more directories . I am still thinking how to get there

Comment: @Raja: Without knowing the pattern, it's hard to tell you more. Maybe just `dir_c/*`?

Comment: Your answer helped me half. Thank you. I will try dir_c* as well and let you know.